# Fix IE Double Margin Bug without "Display Inline"

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fix the "IE Double Margin Bug" without the use of the css property "**display: inline;**" The Reason I ask is because I need to use "display: block;" for my div element to display correctly. Otherwise it will not work.

here is my HTML

```
</head>
<body>
<div class="jimgMenu">
  <ul>
    <li class="landscapes"><a href="#nogo">Landscapes</a></li>
    <li class="people"><a href="#nogo">People</a></li>
    <li class="nature"><a href="#nogo">Nature</a></li>
    <li class="abstract"><a href="#nogo">Abstract</a></li>
    <li class="urban"><a href="#nogo">Urban</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and My CSS

```
.jimgMenu {
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    width: 670px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    left:-42px;
}

.jimgMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1340px;

    }

.jimgMenu ul li {
    float: left;
}

.jimgMenu ul li a {
    text-indent: -1000px;
    background:#FFFFFF none repeat scroll 0%;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:78px;
    height: 200px;
}

.jimgMenu ul li.landscapes a {
    background: url(images/landscapes.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}

.jimgMenu ul li.people a {
    background: url(images/people.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}

.jimgMenu ul li.nature a {
    background: url(images/nature.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}
.jimgMenu ul li.abstract a {
    background: url(images/abstract.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
}

.jimgMenu ul li.urban a {
    background: url(images/urban.jpg) repeat scroll 0%;
    min-width:310px;

}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Why would you try to fix the double margin bug on floated elements when it only manifests in IE5 and 6? ;)

Comment: I don't see any `margin-left` on a floating left element so??

Comment: Ok, I Feel like an Idiot...

Comment: Ok, I Feel like an Idiot... I Had another style sheet I did not look through I had forgoten about that was causing my problem. The reason I Thought it was the "double margin bug" was because of the symptoms I was having and because when i did "display: inline;" it fixed the problem but created a new 1. Also the problem only appeared in IE. Anyway, sorry everybody.